# Anyway to make the uBaseColor value transparent? Three.js && ShaderToon.js

Tags: colors, three.js, shader, opacity

don't know if this is possible, but using the ShaderToon.js in three.js, is there anyway to make the uBaseColor value transparent??? and leave the uLineColor value opaque?

```
function createShaderMaterial( id, light, ambientLight ) {
        var shader = THREE.ShaderToon[ id ];
        var u = THREE.UniformsUtils.clone( shader.uniforms );
        var vs = shader.vertexShader;
        var fs = shader.fragmentShader;
        var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( { uniforms: u, vertexShader: vs, fragmentShader: fs } );
        material.uniforms.uDirLightPos.value = light.position;
        material.uniforms.uDirLightColor.value = light.color;
        material.uniforms.uAmbientLightColor.value = ambientLight.color;
        return material;
}

geometry = new THREE.TorusKnotGeometry(106.68, 200, 12, 2, 8.44, 5.4, 1);
material = createShaderMaterial( "dotted", directionalLight, ambientLight );
material.uniforms.uBaseColor.value.setHex( 0xffffff ); // want this to be transparent
material.uniforms.uLineColor1.value.setHex( 0x0000 );
mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(mesh);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ShaderToon` is part of the examples, so you are free to modify it to your liking.

For example, you could do this:

```
"gl_FragColor = vec4( uBaseColor, 0.5 );",
```

In your `createShaderMaterial()` function, you will also have to set

```
material.transparent = true;
```

three.js r.59

Comment: I see, perfect, thnx so much :)